# On Save of when creating account record create a task (capturing current time and user in description field) using odata

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

**

```js
function task()
{
var date=Date.now();
var accountid=Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var entity = {};

entity.Description = date;
entity.Subject = "Hi.....";
entity.RegardingObjectId = {
            Id:accountid,
            LogicalName: "account"
        };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/TaskSet",
    data: JSON.stringify(entity),
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var result = data.d;
        var newEntityId = result.TaskId;
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

//I try to get date from system and inserted in to task description but it showing.

> Blockquote

Error bad request

> Blockquote

so please help me out ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

the statement :

```
var date=Date.now();
```

captures current date and time and returns as DateTime format.

here is where you went wrong

```
   entity.Description = date;
```

`entity.Description` accepts sting only ..not datetime try converting the variable to string with [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp) also check the other possible [methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

[check for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7vznkjh/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var date=Date.now();` we can use `var date=Date();`

Answer (score 1):

instead of `var date=Date.now();` we can use `var date=Date();' it will work.